# How to redirect a WM_KEYDOWN message to another control in MFC?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I'm on a roll today with MFC! :D

I have a text box and a list view control.

When the user presses the `VK_UP` and `VK_DOWN` keys in the *text box*, I would like this to happen:

1. Do some stuff.
2. Have the list view control **also** process the message (to highlight the previous/next item).
3. I want the list view to **wrap around** the current selection, **if** the key press is the *first* in its sequence.
4. Do some more stuff.

I tried subclassing my edit box in my dialog:

```
class MyEditBox : public CWnd
{
    bool allowWrap;

    afx_msg void OnKeyUp(UINT, UINT, UINT) { this->allowWrap = true; }

    afx_msg void OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
    {
        CListCtrl &listView = static_cast<CListView *>(
            this->GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST_VIEW))->GetListCtrl();

        if (nChar == VK_UP || nChar == VK_DOWN)
        {
            int iSelBefore = listView.GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED);

            this->GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST_VIEW)
                ->OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);  //Oops! Protected member :(

            int iSelAfter  = listView.GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED);

            if (iSelBefore == iSelAfter &&  // Did the selection reach an end?
                this->allowWrap)            // If so, can we wrap it around?
            {
                int i = a == 0 ? listView.GetItemCount() - 1 : 0;
                listView.SetItemState(i, LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED,
                                         LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED);
            }
        }
        this->allowWrap = false;
    }
}
```

but `OnKeyDown()` is a protected member, so I can't just call it on another control.

Is there a **better** way to solve this than manually sending the command with `SendMessage`? Should I change my design, e.g. subclass something else, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Your intention is to select previous or next item in list control, right? Then you should call the method to do that directly instaed of asking the `CListCtrl` to "process" your message.

You may call [CListCtrl::SetSelectionMark](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck58ex74%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [CListCtrl::SetItemState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t97k8h9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to select next or previous keystroke. Example:

```
 cListCtrl.SetSelectionMark(nIndex);
 cListCtrl.SetItemState(nIndex, LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED, 0xFF);
```

You can handle Key Down, Key Up as well as Page Down, Page Up, End, Home or any any key from edit box. You need to do calculation, though.

Or you can just `SendMessage`. There is no need to call `OnKeyDown` directly. Let the framework call it for you when you send the message.

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution, since calling `SendMessage` requires me to create the `wParam` and `lParam` parameters by hand. It's quite possible, but I felt like there should be a better way.

Comment: Your requirement (2) in question is to select previous or next item, and not custom message processing. I have added code to mention how to do that.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how that is relevant to my previous comment, sorry...

Comment: You need some action to happen on list-control, when user does something on edit-box, right?

Comment: Yes, but I do **not** want to tell the list view, "Select the previous item". I want it to react however it would normally do to the up/down keys (and later, Page Up/Page Down keys) -- I don't want to impose any specific behavior by myself.

Comment: Then I believe `SendMessage` is most viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing also other ways to solve this:

1. Derive a class from `CListCtrl` called `MyListCtrl` and choose one of two things:

   1.1 Declare `MyEditBox` as a friend and now you can call the protected methods on `MyEditBox`

   1.2 Add public methods `CallOnKeyDown(...)` and `CallOnKeyup(...)` to it that only do what is needed.

   And when creating the control, instance a `MyListCtrl` instead of a `CListCtrl`. Also replace the `listView` variable you have shown here to be a `MyListCtrl` and use the methods you have now available
2. Use `PreTranslateMessage(...)`. I think this "hammer" solution is worse than sending a message.